# Powershell to delete files older than x days but always keep the newest one

Tags: powershell

I am new to learning powershell and trying to figure out a way to accomplish this. Any help would be appreciated.

I have a bunch of routers and switches that backup configuration via scp.
They name syntax is "hostname-[EPOCH TIMESTAMP].txt"
Which looks like TestRouter-[1650480027].txt

I would like to delete all files older than say 14 days, but always keep the one with the latest epoch timestamp per device.

I am able to come out with regex to sort the epoch dates, but I do not know how to approach the logic for grouping the hostnames.

Does anyone have a good approach for this?

Thank you!

EDIT 1
Balthazar pretty much wrote this for me... Thank you, I am trying to figure out the testing portion of this now. For testing I am trying to change the remove-item to write-output and the time to 5 minutes or seconds. This is not providing any results or errors though.

```
    # location of hostname-epoch.txt files
$Root = "Directory"
# Get All txt Files in $Root and Group on hostname, then loop over each group
Get-ChildItem $Root -Filter '*.txt' | Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('~')[0] } | ForEach-Object {
    # Today at 00:00:00 - Remove 00:00:00 if you don't want it
    $Today = Get-Date 00:00:00
    # Get Files and skip newest one by default
    $CheckFiles = $_.Group | Sort-Object BaseName -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1
    # Loop over CheckFiles
    foreach ($File in $CheckFiles) {
        # Get Epoch from FileName
        $FileEpoch = $File.BaseName.Split('~')[1]
        # Get DateTime Object from Epoch
        $FileTime  = (Get-Date 01.01.1970).AddSeconds($FileEpoch)
        # if Timespan is greater than 14 Days delete the file
        if ((New-TimeSpan $FileTime $Today).Seconds -gt -14) {
            Write-Output $File.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sort by _descending_ age. skip the 1st one. delete all the others. ///// is the file system time stamp close enuf to work? that would be simpler to use ...

Comment: The folder has multiple hostnames, so I have to find a way to keep the latest file of each hostname

Comment: so, sort by date descending, group by hostname, skip the 1st item from each group, and kill the rest. [*grin*]

Comment: ok, that would do it!... Now the how to lol

I was able to change the file syntax to put the hostname between {} and the timestamp between []

This is what I have so far...
$src = "D:\BACKUPS\ConfigChange"
$HostnameFilter = [regex] "(?<={)(.*)(?=})"
$TimestampFilter = [regex] "(\[\d*?\])"

$allfiles = Get-ChildItem $src -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match $HostnameFilter} | 

I am not sure how to actually go about this...

Comment: it looks like Balthazar has the same idea. if that code works, go with it. if not, add the code in your Comment to your Question so that it is readable ... and easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, assuming that:

- splitting the Basename, `hostname` is always at `[0]`
- splitting the Basename, `epoch` is always at `[1]`

Here's the code, everything is commented so you should be able to understand what it does

Change the Value of `$Root`, and backup your files before you run this.

```
# location of hostname-epoch.txt files
$Root = "C:\install\superuser1717233"
# Get All txt Files in $Root and Group on hostname, then loop over each group
Get-ChildItem $Root -Filter '*.txt' | Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] } | ForEach-Object {
    # Today at 00:00:00 - Remove 00:00:00 if you don't want it
    $Today = Get-Date 00:00:00
    # Get Files and skip newest one by default
    $CheckFiles = $_.Group | Sort-Object BaseName -Descending | Select-Object -Skip 1
    # Loop over CheckFiles
    foreach ($File in $CheckFiles) {
        # Get Epoch from FileName
        $FileEpoch = $File.BaseName.Split('-')[1]
        # Get DateTime Object from Epoch
        $FileTime  = (Get-Date 01.01.1970).AddSeconds($FileEpoch)
        # if Timespan is greater than 14 Days delete the file
        if ((New-TimeSpan $FileTime $Today).Days -gt 14) {
            Remove-Item $File.FullName -Force
        }
    }
}
```

The magic happens on `Group-Object { $_.BaseName.Split('-')[0] }` that's where you group the files for each hostname and then loop over them

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to do, and very informative on how to deal with this stuff. I had no idea how simple it was to sort and skip the first file!

I want to test this and see print the results to the screen, but I am not having any luck. I edited my post with the write-output I am trying to do. Do you see what I am messing up?

Comment: @Powershelling instead of write-output, you can just use `Remove-Item $File.FullName -WhatIf`. the WhatIf Parameter tells you what it would do instead of doing it. so it would tell you what files it would remove. You can also use `(New-TimeSpan $FileTime $Today).Seconds -gt 1`. Also, can you tell me one real filename? looks like you changed the splitting